# gcc: passing -nostartfiles to ld via gcc for minimal binary size

Tags: assembly, gcc, ld, gnu-assembler

consider the following gas (GNU assembler) file for 64 bit linux

`go.s`

```asm
        .global _start
        .text

_start:
        mov     $60, %rax               # system call 60 is exit
        xor     %rdi, %rdi              # we want return code 0
        syscall
```

Now to compile:

```bash
rm -f go go.o
as -o go.o go.s
ld -o go -s -nostartfiles go.o
ls -l go                                            # -> 344 bytes
```

We get a super-small size of 344 bytes.

Great! With gcc and separate `ld` command:

```bash
# gcc with separate link
rm -f go go.o
gcc -xassembler -c go.s
ld -s -nostartfiles -o go go.o
ls -l go                                            # -> 344 bytes
```

But **how does one get that small size, using only a single gcc command**?

```bash
# single gcc command                                                                                                                                                                     
rm -f go go.o
gcc -xassembler -s -static -nostartfiles -o go go.s
ls -l go                                            # -> 4400 bytes  too big!!!
```

Damn 4400 bytes! Which single line gcc invocation will give 344 bytes?

Running the above single line with the `-v` flag...

```bash
gcc -v -xassembler -s -static -nostartfiles -o go go.s
```

... shows that
`-nostartfiles` is not passed to the `collect2` link command.

Hmmm...

So task: show me the single-line gcc invocation giving the minimal size!

Thanks.

---

Experimenting with the `-v` flag:

```bash
gcc -v -xassembler -s -static -nostartfiles -o go go.s
```

does the following:

```
as -v --64 -o go.o go.s

# will give 4400 bytes
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -static -o go -s -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../.. go.o --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group
```

Manually adding `-nostartfiles` (directly after `collect2`) in the `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/collect2` command (above) gives a size of 520 bytes.

Manually adding `-nostartfiles` (directly after `collect2`) and removing `--build-id` gives a size of 344 bytes. As we can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316448/15914618), `-Wl,--build-id=none` should remove the build-id.

But how does one instruct gcc to pass `-nostartfiles` to `ld` or `collect2`?

---

In response to Jester's comment:

Doing the following (`-Wl,-nostartfiles`):

```sh
gcc -Wl,-nostartfiles,--build-id=none -v -xassembler -s -static -nostartfiles -o go go.s
```

will add `-nostartfiles` **too far at the end** of the `collect2` command, with the result that the output binary `go` is not even created. How does one give the command, so that `-nostartfiles` occurs earlier in the `collect2 ...` command: I know it works, if I manually construct `-nostartfiles` to be a flag **right at the beginning**.

Looking [here](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-core/issues/843#issuecomment-263848795), there is a claim that `-Wl,-nostartfiles` will not be handled correctly. But if I just use `gcc -nostartflags ...`, then it is not passed to the linker: Maby this is a bug in gcc??

Maby all code gets optimized away... leaving nothing at all?? See [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52267/compiling-with-flto-and-nostartfiles-results-in-no-program-at-all)

Comment: Did you try `-Wl,-nostartfiles`?

Comment: Yes. It does **not** work. The `-v` flag shows that `-nostartfiles` is then added quite at the end of the `collects2` link command (`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/collect2 .... go.o --build-id=none -nostartfiles --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group`); and the result is: the output binary `go` is not even created!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-nostartfiles` is not an `ld` option.  **It parses as `ld -n -o startfiles`.**

I tried your commands, and they don't create a file called `go`, they create an executable called `startfiles`.

```
$ cat > go.s
  paste + control-d
$ as -o go.o go.s
$ ld -o go -s -nostartfiles go.o
$ ll go
ls: cannot access 'go': No such file or directory
$ ll -clrt
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter  193 May 13 11:33 go.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter  704 May 13 11:33 go.o
-rwxr-xr-x 1 peter peter  344 May 13 11:33 startfiles
```

Your `go` must have been left over from your `ld -s -nostartfiles -o go go.o` where `-o go` was the last instance of `-o` on the command line, not overridden by `-o startfiles`.

---

**The option that makes your binary small is `ld -n`:**

> `-n`
> `--nmagic`
> **Turn off page alignment of sections**, and disable linking against shared libraries.  If the output format supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the
> output as "NMAGIC".

Related: [Minimal executable size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago, for tiny programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037919/minimal-executable-size-now-10x-larger-after-linking-than-2-years-ago-for-tiny)

---

As a GCC option, `-nostartfiles` tells the `gcc` front-end *not* to link `crt*.o` files.  If you're running `ld` manually, you just omit mentioning them.  There's no need to tell `ld` what you're not linking, the `ld` command itself doesn't link anything it's not explicitly told to.  Linking CRT files and libc / libgcc are `gcc` defaults, not `ld`.

```
$ gcc -s -nostdlib -static  -Wl,--nmagic,--build-id=none go.s
$ ll a.out 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 peter peter 344 May 13 12:35 a.out
```

**You want `-nostdlib`** to omit libraries as well as CRT start files.
`-nostartfiles` is only a subset of what `-nostdlib` does.
(Although when statically linking, `ld` doesn't pull in any code from `libc.a` or `libgcc.a` because your file doesn't reference any external symbols.  So you actually still get the same 344 byte file from using `-nostartfiles` as `-nostdlib`.  But `-nostdlib` replicates your manual `ld` command more exactly, not passing any extra files.)

You need `-static` to not dynamically link, on a GCC where `-pie` is the default.  (This also implies `-no-pie`; `-static-pie` won't be enabled by default.)
`--nmagic` fails with *error: PHDR segment not covered by LOAD segment* if you let GCC try to dynamically link a PIE executable (even with no shared libraries).

Comment: The OP already mentioned that the build ID can be dropped with `-Wl,--build-id=none`.

Comment: @Armali: Thanks, that reproduces the 344 byte size with `gcc`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!